# Angular js using $rootScope in ng-src script on refresh fails

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-rootscope

I'm creating a project with internationalization, where labels will be in /conf/lang/lang_{{lang}}/labels.js which will included in index.html. 
lang - rootscope variable setting in app.run().
Index.html

```
 <script ng-src="{{labelUrl}}"></script>
```

app.js - run()

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) 
    {

        if($cookieStore.get("config_details") != undefined)
        {
            $rootScope.language = $cookieStore.get("config_details").language;
        }
        else
        {
            $rootScope.language = 'english';
        }
        $rootScope.labelUrl = "conf/lang/lang_"+$rootScope.language+"/labels.js";
})
```

This script file is loading correctly on url changing but when refresh manually the $rootscope value destroys and the script file is loading after html content is loaded.
Somebody help me to resolve this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you try to reload a page everything will be destroyed. Look at this

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

    myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$cookies', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, $cookies, $timeout) {
      if ($cookies.get('lang')) {
        $scope.debug = "Browser has got cookies";
        $rootScope.language = $cookies.get('lang');
      } else {
        $scope.debug = "Browser does not have cookies";
        $timeout(function() {
          $cookies.put('lang', 'en');
          $rootScope.language = 'en';
          $scope.debug = "Browser has got cookies";
        }, 2000);
      }
    }]);
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/grishkovelli/d0405vbv/)

[Try angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

Comment: But cookie will be available right? with tht i can reassign to rootscope na?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then you should get the values from cookie and set to scope before .

Comment: You can do it in run()

Comment: Also, you can do it in a main controller.

Comment: you have used timeout in else part,  what is the use of it?

Comment: It is an example of condition of cookies. I mean if you delete the key "lang" from your cookie and will run the jsfiddle's example you will see what i mean.

Comment: okey i have used this in main controller still js is loading after html content.